# How does a computer know if a directory exists?

Tags: hard-drive

I have heard people saying that a directory takes up no space on a hard drive. If so, how to does a computer know if an empty directory exists

Comment: it takes up *some* space, just not enough to care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most operating systems report a file's size based on just its contents, *not* including the metadata used to track the existence of that file itself.

So an empty file would be reported as "0 bytes" because it holds 0 bytes of data, even though it'll still occupy a non-zero amount of bytes in the filesystem's *metadata* area (e.g. the MFT or the FAT or the inode table).

The same applies to directories – the entry used to record the directory's existence (and name, location, timestamps, owner, etc.) will indeed use some space within the filesystem's metadata, but if the directory itself is empty then that entry might not point to any data allocation yet.

Answer (score 2):

A Filesystem (of whatever type) stores and indexes metadata (data describing data) that tells it things like what files and directories it contains. A directory is usually just an entry in a list of all directories, indexed for fast reads.

Answer (score 0):

The Bantam books' “AmigaDOS manual” in 3rd edition has an entire chapter on `FFS` and `OFS` - the original file systems for the Amiga. (Chapter 9, The Filing System, 15 pages, block content figures and large text).

This isn't the worlds most advanced nor fastest filesystem, but one that is easily understood, and possibly one to study to understand the basics, metadata and all.

AmigaDOS came about from "TriPOS" (Trivial portabe OS?)

https://www.google.com/search?q=amigados+manual+3rd+ed